Google search console error, index page cant be indexed
I have a website learn2hack.io and when i submit to google search console i keep getting errors, first it was duplicate without canonical now its page with redirect error.
i have included
<link rel="canonical" href="https://learn2hack.io" />
on my index.php file and i created rules in .htaccess
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.learn2hack\.io [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://learn2hack.io/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]

I did the redirect in htaccess because chat gpt told me it would fix indexing problems.
how can I get my index page properly indexed? all my other pages seem to be fine except my index.php page file.

Your on-page code contains links to https://learn2hack.io/index.php instead of https://learn2hack.io/ - you ideally need to standardise the link format in the code itself.
I'm assuming that Google Search Console is only showing a redirect for /index.php and not the root URL, as I can see the latter is indexed correctly - when I do a site: search it is there.
If you have external backlinks to /index.php then it will likely remain listed in Google Search Console, but be aware that it is just a warning rather than an error.  It's worth fixing for professionalism, but you won't get any great ranking benefit for doing so.
